# Вывод программы на языке си

Tags: c

При выполнении следующей программы на языке Си при вводе: b , выводом программы будет: 0 . Такой вывод получается при вводе любого символа, отличного от цифры. Хотя по идее должен выводится код символа ascii. Или я что-то не понимаю, объясните, как символ сохраняется в типе переменной int?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    printf("%d",t);
}
```

Comment: Почему должен быть код символа, если вы вполне чётко запросили именно десятичное число?

Comment: Мне нужно ввести именно символ для задачи

Comment: Ну значит открывайте [документацию scanf](https://www.c-cpp.ru/content/scanf) и читайте, какой код отвечает за считывание именно символа

Comment: Вам задачу прислать, чтобы вы её решили? Я знаю, что нужно использовать тип char

Comment: Ну и в чём у вас проблема тогда?

Comment: Человек вводит либо число либо символ, как мне проверить, что он ввёл? Я думал использовать код ascii и думал, что int выводит при вводе символа код этого символа в ascii, поскольку цифры и символы в ascii имеют разный код, и я смогу отличить символ от числа

Comment: Ну да, вы можете проверить код символа, если вы считаете через scanf именно символ, а не десятичное число (документацию на то, как считать символ, я уже привёл выше)

Comment: так в этом и проблема, мой код выводит всегда 0, а не код в ascii

Comment: Так вы считываете десятичное число. Вполне логично, что его не будет, если пользователь введёт не десятичное число

Comment: и что делать нужно, чтобы понять, что ввёл пользователь?

Comment: символ или число

Comment: Вы определитесь, что конкретно вы хотите — «символ или число» или проверить ascii-код символа на наличие цифры? Вы в разных комментариях упоминаете разные задачи, а это так-то очень сильно разные вещи

Comment: и то и другое, человек вводит символы например так: * 5 / / 100 2 2

Comment: нельзя заранее определить, что он введёт

Comment: число или символ

Comment: я хочу узнать, что он ввёл: символ или число. Про код ascii я пишу, как о попытке это узнать

Comment: Считывайте строку и разбирайтесь, в конце концов... Кстати, вы бы проверили, что возвращает `scanf`, чтоб понять для себя, а читает ли она вообще что-нибудь.

Comment: Так пусть пользователь вводит строку, а вы её далее интерпретируйте

Answer (score 0):

Функция `scanf` в строковых аргументах содержит идентификатор типа `%d` как тип `int`. Этот аргумент нужен, так как введённое выражение можно понимать по разному : как букву, строку или число. И функция возвращает значение, которое означает количество распознатых объектов.
Чтобы распознать введённое выражение можно последовательно вызывать чтение разных типов, можно сначала как число, а если произошла неудача, то как буква.

```c
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    if (  scanf ( "%d"  , & t ) != 1 ) {
      char c ;
      if (  scanf ( "%c"  , & c ) != 1 ) {
        printf("ни буква ни число\n");
      } else
        printf("буква = '%c'\n",c);
    } else
      printf("число = %d\n",t);
}
```

*Хотя по идее должен выводится код символа ascii.* - не должен. Читайте инструкции.